# How to enable SAS-12 on LSI 9361 RAID controller

Tags: raid, ssd, sas, lsi

By default, this SAS-12 controller runs with SAS-12 SSDs at SAS-6 speeds.  How to unlock SAS-12?

Answer (score 0):

1. select manage link speed from controller's context menu

[image: select manage link speed from controller's context menu]

2. set it to auto or SAS-12

[image: set it to auto or SAS-12]